# Prove that $f'(z)= \int_0^1 \cos zt \, dt$ where $f(z)=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin zt }{t} \, dt $

Tags: complex-analysis

The complex text (Bak) I'm studying asks me to prove the above by writing $f(z)=\int_0^1 \int_0^z \cos zt \, dz\,dt= \int_0^z (\int_0^1 \cos zt \,dt) \,dz\textrm{,} \textrm{ etc.}$ and provides the following solution: 
$f(z)=\int_0^1 \int_0^z \cos zt \, dz \, dt= \int_0^z (\int_0^1 \cos zt \, dt) \, dz$ so that $f'(z)= \int_0^1 \cos zt \, dt$.

It seems to me that that "solution" is merely restating the problem. Maybe I'm missing the point entirely. Any help would be great, as I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation you/the book has used doesn't make sense, you can't integrate a function with respect to $z$ from $0$ to $z$. The text you are using is just writing

$$\frac{\sin zt}{t} = \int \cos zt \,dz$$

and hence

\begin{align} f(z) &= \int_0^1 \frac{\sin zt}{t} \,dt \\ 
&= \int_0^1 \left( \int \cos zt \,dz \right) \,dt \\ 
&= \int \left( \int_0^1 \cos zt \,dt \right) \,dz \\ 
\implies f'(z) &= \int_0^1 \cos zt \,dt \end{align}

where in the last line, we have used [the fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part). We can justify interchanging the integrals [because the integral is finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus)).